# How to determine a genuine AirPods bud (just one - left) from a fake one?

Tags: airpods

I have my AirPods 1st generation (bought it in the Apple store), the problem is that I lost my left bud, so I am going to buy one.

After research, I found out that there are a lot of not genuine (fake) AirPods spare parts (like buds). After googling it was found out that there are minor diffs between genuine and fake ones, but they all related to the AirPods case. In other words, there is almost no way to find out (if you buy just one bud and not the entire AirPods + case) if you buy origin or a fake one.

So, the question is that true - if you buy just one bud without the case, there is no way to find out is it genuine or fake?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how well done the fake is. You'll have to compare the details of an original to the one you want to buy. There is no single mark that you could compare, as every counterfeit is different. The safest bet to get an official replacement is to buy it at an official source, such as an Authorized Apple Service Provider.